# how to group words as a sentence based on speaker # in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please consider the following example:

I have a DataFrame

| Index | Speaker | Word |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | spk_0 | can |
| 1 | spk_0 | you |
| 2 | spk_0 | see |
| 3 | spk_0 | my |
| 4 | spk_0 | screen |
| 5 | spk_0 | now |
| 6 | spk_0 | ? |
| 7 | spk_1 | yes |
| 0 | spk_1 | , |
| 8 | spk_1 | now |
| 9 | spk_1 | I |
| 10 | spk_1 | can |
| 11 | spk_1 | see |
| 12 | spk_1 | your |
| 13 | spk_1 | screen |
| 14 | spk_1 | . |
| 15 | spk_0 | Let |
| 16 | spk_0 | me |
| 17 | spk_0 | start |
| 18 | spk_0 | then |
| 19 | spk_2 | yes |
| 20 | spk_2 | sure |

I want to combine the Word column such that it should look like the following:

| Index | Speaker | Sentence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | spk_0 | can you see my screen now ? |
| 1 | spk_1 | yes , now I can see your screen . |
| 2 | spk_0 | let me start then . |
| 3 | spk_2 | Yes sure . |

Can someone please help me find a solution to this problem?
I already had tried group by but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by consecutive values of `Speaker` column created by comapred shifted value with cumulative sum and aggregate `join`:

```
g = df['Speaker'].ne(df['Speaker'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df.groupby(['Speaker', g],sort=False)['Word'].agg(' '.join).droplevel(-1).reset_index()
print (df)
  Speaker                               Word
0   spk_0        can you see my screen now ?
1   spk_1  yes , now I can see your screen .
2   spk_0                  Let me start then
3   spk_2                           yes sure
```